# nested queries in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have json data as follows

```
{
  "_index": "project",
  "_type": "ts_order_snapshot",
  "_id": "1",
  "_version": 1,
  "exists": true,
  "_source": {
    "order_id": "100000001",
    "order_data": "Order Data:{\"entity_id\":\"1\",\"state\":\"canceled\"}"
  }
}
```

Now I would like to get the list of all the order ids having state as canceled. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`order_data` is a serialized, json-encoded string, not a structured json map. If you promoted it to actual json, you could construct a query like `?q=order_data.state:canceled&fields=order_id`.

Comment: I am very new to JSON also. Could you please elaborate on this. How to transform this `serialized JSON encoded string` to `actual JSON`.

Comment: is this a fine encoding?  `{"_index":"project","_type":"ts_order_snapshot","_id":"1","_version":55,"exists":true, "_source" : {"order_id":"100000001","order_data":{"entity_id":"1","state":"canceled"}}}`  
And could you suggest me a query to get the results.

Comment: Yes, that's what you want. See the query example in my first response.